# Clean up metadata Azure SQL Sync Database

Tags: database, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Trying to create Azure Data Sync Group but every time when I create it, it throw following error

```
Failed to perform data sync operation: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

After days of struggle I found a way to change my error :(
Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure) article to delete the existing Metadata Group.

https://github.com/vitomaz-msft/DataSyncMetadataCleanup/blob/master/Data%20Sync%20complete%20cleanup.sql

I cleared all the existing Metadata Group but when I try to create new one, field is still disable and I cannot change it.

[image]

Also when I try to use the same Metadata Group it is now throwing me this error
[image]

PS: I cannot delete and recreate the existing database which is right now appearing on ' Sync Metadata Database '

Any thoughts, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the deprovision tool. Under the "C:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Azure Data Sync" directory you should find an utility named deprovisionUtil.exe. That tool can be run with the /F switch to remove the DSS schema and objects installed by SQL Data Sync.

If you came to know about the deprovision tool too late and you started to manually uninstall Azure SQL Data Sync objects already, it is very probable you have left some remnants that won't allow you to configure SQL Data Sync successfully again. Those remnants may also create issues when importing an Azure SQL database on an on-premises SQL Server instance.

If you started a manual clean up of Azure SQL Data Sync, the [Data Sync Metadata Cleanup](https://github.com/vitomaz-msft/DataSyncMetadataCleanup) created by Vitor Tomaz (MSFT) may help.

If the Data Sync Metadata Cleanup script does not help, then consider creating a support ticket, Azure support may need to provide you a complete cleanup script.